# Possible arrangements of the letters of the word "Polyunsaturated" in which the vowel order is preserved

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many possible arrangements can we sort the letters of the "Polyunsaturated" so that the vowel order is preserved in this word?

I think **$p,l,y,n,s,t,r,t,d$** have $\frac{9!}{2!}$ possible arrangements, because "**$t$**" have $2$ repetition.

**$o,u,a,u,a,e$** must sit in $10$ places between **$p,l,y,n,s,t,r,t,d$** and left and right of that. But I don't know how count them so that preserved this order.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "vowel order"?  $_o_ _u_ _a_u_a_e_$ or just $ouauae$ should be in order from left to right?

Comment: Please [do not just ask. Include your work.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)

Comment: Surely you must have tried *something* ? Pl. edit it in.

Answer (score 6):

**For an another way using probability:**

What is the probability that $a,a,u,u,e,o$ will be in the form of correct alphabetical order ? The answer is : $$\frac{1}{6!/(2!2!)}=\frac{1}{180}$$

Now, when we order the letters of "**Polyunsaturated**", $1/180$ of these arrangements will be in the form that vowels are in alphabetical order.

Then , $$\frac{15!}{2!2!2!}\times \frac{1}{180}=908,107,200$$

**For the third approach:**

The word "**Polyunsaturated**" has $15$ letters, so we can think that there are $15$ empty places for replacing these letters.Firstly, lets select $6$ place for vowels among these $15$ places by $C(15,6)$ ways. When we select these $6$ places, the letters can be replaced in only one way such that they are in the form of alphabetical order.After that, we now have $9$ places to place these $9$ constonants.We can order them $9!/2!$ ways in a line.Then, $$\binom{15}{6}\times \frac{9!}{2!}=5005 \times 181,440=908,107,200$$

Comment: Nice use of probability (+1)

Answer (score 4):

Corrected, thanks to @Daniel Mathias

- Place the 6 vowels together in a line, in the order in which they appear in the word
- Consider the consonants as balls and insert them one by one in $ 7.8.9.10.11.12.13.14.15$ ways. (The first ball can be placed in $7$ ways, and each ball placed creates an extra space for the next one. )
- Divide by $2$ to take care of the repeated consonant.

Comment: The permutations are not restricted to one vowel per gap.

Comment: $+1$ for classical approach :)